2d pixel/ Python 3.11+, mini game PyXel lib\simple

need to implement player rendering on the map, add collision for objects below...I write in Python 3.13+ with the PyXel library to create simple 2D pixel games




import pyxel
from pyxel.pyxel_wrapper import tilemap
class Game:
    pyxel.init(128, 128, title="SimleWorld")
    pyxel.load("mygame.pyxres")


    def can_move(self, x):
        """"""

        def __init__(self):
            self.tile_width = 8  #
            self.player_width = 4  #
            self.player_height = 4
            self.player_x = 4  #
            self.player_y = 4  #
            self.player_speed = 1

    pyxel.run(self.update, self.draw)

    """
    if pyxel.btn(pyxel.KEY_LEFT):
        player.move_left()
    elif pyxel.btn(pyxel.KEY_RIGHT):
        player.move_right()
    elif pyxel.btnp(pyxel.KEY_Q):
        pyxel.quit()
    """


def draw(self):
    pyxel.cls(0)  # CleenCash)

    # Рисуем карту
    pyxel.bltm(4, 4, 0, 0, 0, pyxel.width, pyxel.height)

    # Рисуем игрока
    player = 

Game()

[[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/rEZHDDJk.jpg)](https://i.sstatic.net/H3J3GKbO.jpg)





1. bro, I didn't figure out the controls here, I need the tile to be drawn at x 3.3 y 4.4, and the tile size in the editor is x - 17.17, y - 30, 30, I hope I'm explaining it clearly...

2. check for collision with WALL(0,0) # BLOCK on tile sheet that is used for the floor
3ю add player spawn

